# Hey! I am not able to insert html form data to MySQL database using NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

When I try to submit the form I receive

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Fname' of undefined.

Please anyone help me by telling me what is the error. Here is my `contact.html` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>contact</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/contact.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <section id="contactsection1">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="/">CodeSmashers</a>
        <h3>Learn Coding with us</h3>
      </div>
      <label id="icon" onclick="ToggleMenu()">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </label>
      <nav id="navbar">
        <ul id="manu">
          <li class="item"><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="/about">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="/blog">BLOG</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="/contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <h1>Contact</h1>
    </section>

    <section id="contactsection2">
      <form method="POST" action="/contact" id="form" type="submit">
        <div id="forminput">
          <input type="text" name="Fname" placeholder="First Name" />
          <input type="text" name="Lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
          <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="subject" />
          <textarea
            class="inputtext"
            name="message"
            id="massege"
            cols="30"
            rows="10"
            placeholder="Your Massege"
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <button class="btn">Send Massege</button>
      </form>
    </section>

    <footer>
      <nav id="navfooter">
        <ul id="manu">
          <li class="item"><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="/about">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="/blog">BLOG</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="/contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="social_icons">
        <img src="img/twiter.png" alt="twiter" class="social" />
        <img src="img/facobook.jpg" alt="facebook" class="social" />
        <img src="img/instagram.png" alt="instagram" class="social" />
        <img src="img/youtube.png " alt="youtube" class="youtube" />
      </div>
    </footer>
    <hr />
    <h4 class="copyright">
      Copyright@ <a href="/">CodeSmashers</a> | All rights reserved!
    </h4>

    <script>
      let menu = document.getElementById("manu");

      function ToggleMenu() {
        if (menu.style.display == "none") {
          menu.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          menu.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is my node app:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
var mysql = require("mysql");

var con = mysql.createconnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "codesmashers",
  table: "contactinfo",
});

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.get("/about", function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + "/about.html");
});

app.get("/blog", function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + "/blog.html");
});

app.get("/contact", function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + "/contact.html");
});

app.post("/contact", function (req, res) {
  var fname = req.body.fname;
  var lname = req.body.lname;
  var subject = req.body.subject;
  var message = req.body.message;
  res.write('you sent the fname "' + req.body.fname + '".\n');
  res.write('you sent the lname "' + req.body.lname + '".\n');
  res.write('you sent the subject "' + req.body.subject + '".\n');
  res.write('you sent the message "' + req.body.message + '".\n');

  con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log("connected to database!");
    var sql =
      "insert into form (fname, lname, subject, message) values ('" +
      fname +
      "', '" +
      lname +
      "','" +
      subject +
      "'.'" +
      message +
      "')";
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("inserted successfully!");
      res.end();
    });
  });
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("application started listening at port 3000");
});
```

I am able to enter the form data but, I am not able to insert it to the database. please mention where I am doing wrong. remaining things in node app are working well but, in the `fname` field, there is an error. thanks in advance.

Comment: log what's coming under ‘req.body‘

Answer (score 1):

You should declare a middleware with express.urlencoded() method.

Your server side app wont accept form data because of this.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4296402/14310085